# Out of IP address on DHCP 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, ip

Hi I have 250+ workstations on IP's from 192.168.1.3 to 192.168.1.254 subnet 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.1 and our server on 192.168.1.2

We are expanding and need to add another 254 IP's but this is where i am a bit stuck as I have never had to do it before.

I have tried expanding the range from 192.168.1.3 to 192.168.2.254 with a subnet of 255.255.254.0 lenth was /23 when i set it on the scope.

However soon as an IP hits 192.168.2.x I get no connection I can see on the server the workstation is connected but no internet.

Do i need to do anything to the main router?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you update your router to deal with this /23?

Answer (score 2):

`192.168.1.3 to 192.168.2.254` aren't in the same /23. You need to either use 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.1.0 or .2.0 and .3.0 if you are set on the /23 subnet size.

Better yet, switch to an even larger subnet; I'd recommend a /21 using 192.168.0.x to 192.168.7.x as that's approximately the largest a broadcast domain modern hardware can handle. You wont have to go through this sort of issue ever again (more likely than not) at this size.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I will give this a try once I get the company who deal with the router in as i cannot access it